# How to apply a function to severals pandas columns as arguments?

Tags: pandas, function, apply

Please can you help me to resolve my daily problem?
I have a panda dataframe df with 2 columns called:

```
MatSituation  NbChild 
    1         0
    2         1
    3         0
    4         1
```

I want to create a new column with a function f which have "MatSituation" and "NbChild" arguments:

```
df[n_NbChild] = df['MatSituation ','NbChild '].apply(.....)
```

How can i manage this situation please?

Thanks a lot.
Thierry

```
df['n_Age'] = df['Age'][dataset['Age'].notnull()].apply(age_classify)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a function that accepts two inputs and returns a value and then assign to it a new column.

For example:

```
def sum_two_columns(a, b):
    return a + b


df['New Column'] = sum_two_columns(df.MatSituation, df.NbChild)

df

MatSituation  NbChild   New Column
    1         0            1
    2         1            3
    3         0            3
    4         1            5
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I tried your proposition but first parameter seems be row index:            def NbEnfNull(x,y):
    print("Le code est {} et le nb d\'enfant est {}".format(x,y))                                                                                             dataset['n_nbr_enf'] = NbEnfNull(dataset['COD_SIS_FAM'],dataset['NBR_ENF'])                  Output: Le code est 0       2
1       2
2       4
3       3
4       1
5       1
6       1     Then first parameter id a value between 1 and 4 so i don't understand...

Answer (score 1):

if  age_classify is a function which accepts row as an argument - the only think you have to modify is :
df['n_Age'] = df['Age'][dataset['Age'].notnull()].apply(age_classify, **axis=1**)

Answer (score 0):

I modified my function:

```
def NbEnfNull(x,y):
    if (y.empty):
        if (x == 1 or x == 2): 
            return 0
        elif (x == 3 or x == 4): 
            return 1   
    else:
        return y
```

Call:

```
df['n_nbr_enf'] = NbEnfNull(df['COD_SIS_FAM'],df['NBR_ENF'])
```

But i have null value for df['n_nbr_enf']

```
df['n_nbr_enf'].isnull().sum()
```

1472
I don't know how to progress...
Thanks a lot.